# How do I get units that do not consume food?

Tags: freeciv

I know that there are circumstances where units that usually consume food do not consume food:

- Starting units at the beginning of the game do not consume food (e.g. settlers and workers provided at the beginning of the game do not consume food).
- Units found in huts do not consume food (e.g. legions found in huts do not consume food).

Are there other places where I can get units that do not consume food points?